# Express res.render breaks extends layout when using deep url paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

If I stay one level deep in my app /level1 and call res.render(myPage.jade) everything runs great but when I go to /level1/level2 res.render(myPage.jade) I get 404s on all my css/js and my styling breaks.

Folder Structure

- views
- pages
- pages/myPage.jade
- layout.jade

#### mypage.jade

```
extends ../layout
```

Comment: can you show some of the HTML to demonstrate what your URLs you are calling look like?

Comment: You are probably messing up relative links to your other resources, but honestly, we can't help you other than a wild guess without seeing the relevant portions of the actual templates that are causing you problems.  Questions here should nearly always contain relevant code of some kind because that's the only way we can help you precisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use absolute link for resource try `/css/...` not use `css/...` (same with js file)

Comment: I ended up changing the layout.jade file from                                                 `// Bootstrap Core CSS link(href='../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')`   to   `// Bootstrap Core CSS
    link(href='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')` and everything works perfect!